# What is this error when I using Pipe in R

Tags: r, pipe

```
df2$Neighborhood %>% length()
df2$category %>% length()
table(df2$Neigborhood) %>% [order()]
```

This is the code I write to learn how to use the pipe. I'm not familiar with how to use it yet. An error occurred and I don't know how to fix it.

```
    [1] 481376
    [1] 481376
     Unknown or uninitialised column: 'Neigborhood'.integer(0)
```

The first two lines are able to generate a result. But not the third one. It means the neighborhood column is available. However, there are some mistakes in it. My purpose was to sort the table using function d2[order(d2)]. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is 'h' missing in 'Neigborhood'.  If we use the correct column name i.e. `Neighborhood`, it should work if we also specify the data i.e. `.` from the `lhs` of `%>%`

```
library(magrittr)
table(df2$Neighborhood) %>% 
      .[order(.)]
```

---

It may be also better to wrap with `{}` if there are multiple things involved

```
table(df2$Neighborhood) %>%
             {.[order(.)]}
```

Here the `.` represents the data from the `lhs` of `%>%`